# Parse value containing special character "/" gives wrong output using SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I am have below xml structure

```
  <fs:AsReportedItem>
     <fs:BookMark>/BODY[1]/DIV[3135]/DIV[0]/TABLE[0]/TBODY[0]/TR[32]/TD[5]/DIV[0]/FONT[0]/substr(1,2)
     </fs:BookMark>
  </fs:AsReportedItem>
```

I am parsing using SAX and reading tax value in the endElement() method

Here is my sample code

```
private void parseDocument() {
        // parse
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(FileName, this);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("ParserConfig error");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("SAXException : xml not well formed");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error");
        }
    }

public void startElement(String s, String s1, String elementName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

if (OrgDataPartitonObj != null && "fs:FinancialStatementLineItemDataItem".equals(OrgDataPartitonObj.getType())) {

                FinancialStatementLineItemParser.startFinancialStatementLineItemParser(OrgDataPartitonObj,financialStatementLineItemObj, elementName, attributes);

            }
        }


public void endElement(String s, String s1, String element) throws SAXException {

if (OrgDataPartitonObj != null && "fs:FinancialStatementLineItemDataItem".equals(OrgDataPartitonObj.getType())) {

                 FinancialStatementLineItemParser.getEndElementFinancialStatementLineItemParser(financialStatementLineItemObj, element, tmpValue);
        }
}


public static void getEndElementFinancialStatementLineItemParser(FinancialStatementLineItem financialStatementLineItemObj, String element, String tmpValue) {

            if (element.equals("fs:BookMark")) {
            financialStatementLineItemObj.setBookMark(tmpValue);
        }

    }
   @Override
    public void characters(char[] buffer, int start, int length) {
        tmpValue = new String(buffer, start, length);
    }
```

When i debug then i can see only this value `/substr(1,2)` all value with `"/"` is escaped

I dont know why i am not getting full value `/BODY[1]/DIV[3135]/DIV[0]/TABLE[0]/TBODY[0]/TR[32]/TD[5]/DIV[0]/FONT[0]/substr(1,2)`

If any escape character is used then where i have to use .

Comment: Why is `"/"` being escaped?

Comment: @DevilsHnd that what my question is

Comment: It has nothing to do with "/". The characters()-method of the Sax-DefaultHandler always returns a limited count of characters. To get the full text you must collect the texts of the characters()-method.

Comment: Just to expand on the answer from @RalfRenz: a SAX parser can break up text and hand it over in multiple calls of characters(). It can split the text anywhere it chooses, but many parsers find it convenient to split it at points where entity expansion occurs.

Comment: @MichaelKay so what change do you suggest in order to get full text

Comment: @RalfRenz has shown you the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change character() method

```
@Override
    public void characters(char[] buffer, int start, int length) {
        tmpValue += new String(buffer, start, length);
    }
```

And add this at last line in the endElement method .

```
public void endElement(String s, String s1, String element) throws SAXException {

if (OrgDataPartitonObj != null && "fs:FinancialStatementLineItemDataItem".equals(OrgDataPartitonObj.getType())) {

  FinancialStatementLineItemParser.getEndElementFinancialStatementLineItemParser(financialStatementLineItemObj, element, tmpValue);
        }
tmpValue="";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the sourcecode for a DefaultHandler which collects the text:

```
private static DefaultHandler getHandler() {
    return new DefaultHandler() {
        String text;

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
                throws SAXException {
            if ("BookMark".equals(qName)) {
                text = "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            text += new String(ch).trim();
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            if ("BookMark".equals(qName)) {
                System.out.println("endElement: " + text);
            }
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: How does it solves my problem .What i need to do in order to get full text

Comment: I am getting the value but i am not getting full value in the `text` itself

Comment: Why don't you show the code you have written to parse the xml? Then it is easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your characters()-method to

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] buffer, int start, int length) {
    tmpValue += new String(buffer, start, length);
}
```

and you must reset tmpValue in the startElement()-method to "".